# Xbox 360 for linux programming

Tags: linux, programming-languages, xbox360, kdevelop

somehow I got an xbox 360 4gb as a gift. I am not interested in videogames, I just wonder whether some linux version could be installed on it, and then use it at home for programming, using the same tools I use at work (kdevelop, kile, gcc, etc).

I surfed the web a while ago, but found just confusing info, do you think it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: How come someone who isn't interested in videogames can get given an XBox?! That's not fair!

Comment: life is complicated, sometimes you get the things you are not interested in, and the opposite :-P

Answer (score 2):

While the original [Xbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox) mostly used commodity PC electronics and was therefore [almost a PC](http://www.xbox-linux.org/wiki/FAQ#The_Xbox_is_a_standard_PC.2C_isn.27t_it.3F), the [Xbox360](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360) has a [completely different architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_hardware) and incorporated much more effective methods against running code unauthorised by Microsoft (and yes, Linux is not
authorised).

As it stands now, it is [possible to run Linux on Xbox360](http://free60.org/FAQ), but you need to perform at least some [hardware modifications](http://free60.org/Run_Code#Modified_Drive) to do so.

In short: It can be done, but it won't be easy (and depending on where you live it might also be illegal - standard disclaimers apply).